# Program returns syntax error on def calculation1

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, function

```
#ask the user for how many books they would like
def books_needed():
    number_books = int(raw_input("How many books would you like?:"))
    if number_books <0 or number_books >80:
        number_books = raw_input(int("Number of books cannot be less than 0 or greater than 80. Enter another number:"

#calculates the cost of the books
def calculation1(number_books):
    cost_books = number_books * float(15.99)
    return cost_books

#selects the correct discount percentage to apply
def calculation2(number_books):
    if number_books <= 51 and number_books >= 81:
        discount = int(10)
    elif number_books <=11 and number_books >= 50:
        discount = float(7.5)
    elif number_books <= 6 and number_books >= 10:
        discount = int(5)
    elif number_books <= 1 and number_books >= 5:
        discount = int(1)
    return discount

#works out the cost of books divided by 100
def calculation3(discount,cost_books):
    total = cost_books/100
    return total

#multiplies the number by the correct discount
def calculation4(total,discount):
    full_discount = total * discount
    return full_discount

#calculates the total cost of the books including discount
def calculation5(full_discount):
    final_cost = cost_books - full_discount
    return final_cost

#displays the result
def display_results(final_cost):
    print
    print"Your final price is £", final_cost

#main program
books_needed()
cost_books = calculation1(number_books)
discount = calculate2(number_books)
total = calculation3(discount,cost_books)
full_discount = calculation4(total,discount)
final_cost = calculation5(full_discount)
display_results(final_cost)
```

The error occurs on calcualtion 1 on the def to be precise. can copy the exact error if needed. as far as im aware the rest of the program is ok. If anything else appears to be out, please tell me. thanks

Comment: thanks @Martijn. now it returns a traceback error on line 52, the bit at the bottom that starts cost_books = calculation1(number_books) saying number_books is not defined??

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to some closing parenthesis on the previous line:

```
number_books = raw_input(int("Number of books cannot be less than 0 or greater than 80. Enter another number:"
#   two opening parens 1^  2^        but at the end here ---------------------------------- no closing parens ^
```

You need to add *two* `)` characters at the end there, to close both the `int()` and `raw_input()` calls:

```
number_books = raw_input(int("Number of books cannot be less than 0 or greater than 80. Enter another number:"))
```

That is still wrong, however, because the `"Number .."` string is not convertible to an integer. You probably want to invert the two calls to:

```
number_books = int(raw_input("Number of books cannot be less than 0 or greater than 80. Enter another number:"))
```

to turn the return value of `raw_input()` (the user input) into an integer.

Other notes:

- You don't need to convert number literals into `float()` and `int()`:

  ```
  cost_books = number_books * 15.99  # 15.99 is a float already

  discount = 10    # 10 is an integer already

  discount = 7.5   # 7.5 is a float already
  ```
- Your `books_needed()` function doesn't *return* anything. Return the `number_books` from the function to use later on. Use a loop to keep asking for the number until you have a valid number:

  ```
  def books_needed():
      while True:
          try:
              number_books = int(raw_input("How many books would you like?:"))
              if 1 <= number_books <= 80:
                  return number_books
          except ValueError:
              # not a number, at all
              pass
          print "Number of books must be between 1 and 80."
  ```

  and then at the end use:

  ```
  number_books = books_needed()
  ```

Comment: ive sorted that bit, now i get this error:  line 52, in <module>
    cost_books = calculation1(number_books)
NameError: name 'number_books' is not defined
>>>

Comment: See my updated answer; `number_books` is a local variable in the `books_needed()` function, you need to *return* that value and store it in a global variable (which can be the same name, as shown here).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the closing brackets on your `raw_input`, immediately before the `def` line. That's what's causing your problem.

On top of that, you have the `raw_input` and `int` transposed. The former gets the string and the latter turns that into an integer. Hence it should be:

```
int (raw_input( ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use raw_input  in the line: number_books = int(raw_input("How many books would you like?:"))

instead you should just use input: number_books = input("How many books would you like?:")